# PHP process works fine with default 128M memory but fails when memory increased to 150M

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

We have a class based PHP script that operates on a multiple strings with the longest once of length 475k. This string gets exploded in an array of 30k elements.

Now, when I run the script with default memory limits (PHP Cli) the process works perfectly fine but when I try to increase memory limit to 150M, it fails with "Allocated memory exhausted" error on line that explodes string to array. As per error the explode function itself tries to allocate another 158M memory when script fails.

We tried watching memory usages under 'top', when using 128M the garbage collection triggers around 120M pulling memory usages to 94M. When memory limit is changed to 150M garbage collection does not trigger at all or at least it is not visible in 'top'.

Any idea why PHP is behaving like this. I know I can get going with default limit but knowing the reason behind this would help.

System: Mac OS Sierra
PHP: 7.0.14

Comment: A stab in the dark: Could it be that you have increased a 'per request' memory allocation beyond what you have in total?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try allocating 256M instead of 150M?

Since 150M is not a boundary block value, 128M -> 256M -> 512M -> etc.

Will the problem still occur?

Comment: Yes, 150 is not a block value but same process works normally with 180M which is again, not a block value.

Comment: Yea true, very strange... sorry can't help you any further